# Check if a pixel is transparent or NOT - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, png

I have a PNG picture (With transparent pixels in the corners), i am trying to extract the color code of these transparent pixels , i used a xxxx website that gives me the hand to select a pixel and it returns its color code ;

after selecting the transparent pixels i get : 
RGB code:   R: 34 G: 62 B: 74

that's not logic

i used  BitmapDrawable with my PNG Image // Not a right method i think

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

Is there any way to check if a pixel is transparent or not ?

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
int transparency = ((bitmap.getPixel(x,y) & 0xff000000) >> 24);
```

`transparency` will be between **0** (`completely transparent`) and **255** (`completely opaque`).

Comment: which value the transparency variable should get to check if the picture is transparent or NOT?

Comment: added explanation in the answer.

Comment: @Omar_0x80 , int transparency from 0 to 255, 0 is complety transparent: `if(transparency == 0){ it is transparent }`

Answer (score 3):

this accepted approach is correct also i think better if  use this :

> if (sourceBitmap1. getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know transparency while touching the view, I am using the function below to check if touched pixel is transparent or not:

```
public boolean isBitmapTransparent(ImageView imageview){
    boolean isTransparent = false;
    final Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imageview.getBackground()).getBitmap();
    imageview.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            int eventPadTouch = event.getAction();

            switch (eventPadTouch) {

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (event.getX()>=0 & 
                    event.getY()>=0 & 
                    event.getX()<bitmap.getWidth() & 
                    event.getY()<bitmap.getHeight()) {           
                        if (bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY())!=0) {
                            //TODO pixel not transparent
                            isTransparent = false;
                        }               
                        else{
                            //TODO pixel transparent
                            isTransparent = true;
                        }
                }
                return true;     
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    return isTransparent;
}
```

Comment: sorry but why the downvote for a working answer that I already use in my project??

Comment: sorry, but your transparency check is incorrect. Suppose you have a pixel 0x00FFFFFF, it is not equal to 0, but still is fully transparent.

Comment: yes...but they still attempted to make a good answer. i see no reason for downvoting

Comment: We can use "or" operator to compare pixels. Eg: pixel == 0 || pixel == 0x00FFFFFF || pixel == 0x00000000