# Handling the event of touching non-transparent parts of an imageview

Tags: android, transparency

I'm working on my first game app, when user touches an image the app shows a message to the user (or does other things in other situations).
My photos are non-geometric shapes (for example animal photos) with 100% transparent backgrounds

[image: like this]

(I used Photoshop and saved them in PNG format.)

My problem is that I need it to react (and show the message,...) **only** when the animal shape itself (NOT the imageview's transparent background/corners) is touched by user.

I used the solution that's offered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23045848/check-if-a-pixel-is-transparent-or-not-android) to find out if the pixel that's touched is transparent or not, but it doesn't work the way I need. Here's part of my onCreate() method in MainActivity.java:

```
tempIV=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.birdIV);
final Bitmap bitmap = (BitmapDrawable)tempIV.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
tempIV.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
        int x = (int)event.getX();
        int y = (int)event.getY();
        int transparency = bitmap.getPixel(x,y);
        if (transparency == 0)
             { //Do nothing
              return false;}
        else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "This is an animal!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
            return true;
    }
  });
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :-

```
if (bitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)
{
    return false; //don't react
}
else
{
    return true; //do something like intent
}
```

Comment: Tried this too, but just like my own code, it looks like the app's reaction to user's click is not 100% what expected; sometimes it considers 100% transparent pixels opaque and vice versa.